# running out of memory so quickly-tensorflow-gpu

Tags: tensorflow, memory, gpu

when i run https://github.com/cysmith/neural-style-tf project  my gpu has a spike in device manager graphic as shown below.

tensorflow:2.3.0
python:3.7.9
CUDA:11.1
gpu:nvidia 840m

[exact moment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkqPY.png)   then it drops to zero.

and i get "tensorflow allocator (gpu_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate..." error.

[i dont know why](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kt1OB.png)  there are tons of topic about it but i couldnt find answer for me.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's a problem with memory allocation, can you try adding this snippet just after importing TensorFlow?

```py
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
if gpus:
  try:
    for gpu in gpus:
      tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)
  except RuntimeError as e:
    print("Error: " + e)
```

You can also try setting `TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH` to `TRUE` in your env.

This lets you tell TensorFlow to slowly increase the amount of memory allocated from your graphics card, based on the usage.